# Remove first letter from output

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I remove first letter from this string

```
d[],e[], [dsh,sj]
```

I get this by doing an analysis but now I need to remove first letter before every comma(`,`). So,I storing it and applying for loop but it is giving me error.

```
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [*
```

But I am not understanding why?

EDIT : I know how to remove element but here I am not able to declare it

```
Expected Output :  [],[],[dsh,sj]
```

Comment: Can you add your code? What is your expected output for this string?

Comment: Can you provide the current code that fails?

Comment: I am not doing anything the prior analysis is not related to question. I just pasted to view in console but got result in error

Comment: Tried using substring?

Comment: Just give us the input values and the expected output.

Comment: yes but how it is giving me error even in declaring

Comment: @ppasler I have edited the question

Comment: So you only want to keep values inside '[]' separated by ','?

Comment: are you trying to declare these as array's, as a string?  var s = "d[],e[], [dsh,sj]";  missing quotes?  please paste your code into the question

Comment: @ppasler yes I want the same

Comment: @Paul no there is no quotes

Comment: @shv22 if you are declaring this as a string, that is one of the causes of the syntax error than.

Comment: So it is not a string

Comment: Here: `"d[],e[], [dsh,sj]".replace(/.\[/g,"[")`. TESTED, but not sure it's what you want.

Comment: @PaulZepernick so how do I declare even I am declaring it is an array it is then also giving error

Comment: a String would be declared like: var s = "my string"; an array of Strings would be like var a = ["value1", "value2"];  you can edit your answer and provide your code so we can see what you are attempting to do in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure we are talking about the same things:

```
var s = "hello"; // a String, notice the quotes
var a = [] // an empty Array
var b = ["hello", "bye"] // an Array with 2 elements
```

If this is your input:

```js
var inpt = "d[],e[], [dsh,sj]";
var otpt = inpt.replace(/.\[/g,"["); // returns '[],[],[dsh,sj]' but as data type String

// this block is not very clean...
var splt = otpt.replace(/],/g, "],,");
splt = splt.split(",,");

var arr = [];
splt.forEach(function(value) {
  value = value.replace(/\[|\]/g,"");
  if (value === "") {
 value = [];
  } else {
 value = value.split(",");
  }
  arr.push(value);
});

console.log(arr); // [[],[],["dsh","sj"]]
```

I would recommend to have a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: thanks @ppasler can you please also suggest me how to store each element before comma in a different variable

Comment: Sure, what dataype do you want? String or Array?

Comment: in an array...so that I can split up each of the element

Comment: So from `input = "d[],e[], [dsh,sj]"` you want `x1 = []; x2 = []; x3 = ["dsh", "sj"]`?

Comment: I am just curious, where do you get this kind of data? Whats the use case?

Comment: I exactly don't know as I not in that project but it is related to do business intelligence...I just have given this task as I am new

Comment: This adds the result in an array.